# Powershell Workflows

Tags: powershell, powershell-workflow

I wrote a PowerShell workflow that analyses the Excel data and triggers a mail based on the values in Excel.

I have developed a workflow which triggers mail but I'm having trouble in analysing the Excel data, where I couldn’t call the `Send-Mail` workflow.

Note: column “E-remainder 1” and “F-remainder 2” contains the date of the remainder mail to be sent.

```
Workflow test {
    $worksheet = InlineScript {
        $objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
        $objExcel.Visible = $false
        $WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open(#filepath)
        $worksheet = $workbook.Sheets.Item(#sheetname)
        $currentdate = (Get-Date).ToString()

        $rownumber = #contains rownumber from excel whose details has to be mailed

        foreach ($i in $rownumbers) {
            if ($worksheet.Range("B$i").Text -eq $currentdate) {
                $output = [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
                    ComputerName = $WorkSheet.Range("C$i").Text
                    Fromaddress = $WorkSheet.Range("D$i").Text
                    Toaddress = $WorkSheet.Range("E$i").Text
                }
                # I need to call a workflow which sends a mail
                # (workflow which I have to trigger mail)
                Send-Mail -To $output.Toaddress -From $output.Fromaddress -Name $output.ComputerName
            } elseif ($worksheet.Range("F$i").Text -eq $currentdate) {
                $output = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
                    ComputerName = $WorkSheet.Range("C$i").Text
                    Fromaddress = $WorkSheet.Range("D$i").Text
                    Toaddress = $WorkSheet.Range("E$i").Text
                }
                # I need to call a workflow which sends a mail
                # (Based on my knowledge I know that we couldn't call a workflow inside the inline script)
                Send-Mail -To $output.Toaddress -From $output.Fromaddress -Name $output.ComputerName
            }
        } # foreach ends
    } # Inline ends
} # workflow ends
```

Im getting the following error:

> ERROR:The term "Send-Mail" is not recognized as the name of the cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: You need to provide a bit more. Tell us what you tried, what error(s) you're receiving, where in the script it fails, etc. Please see [ask]. Provide a [mcve] if possible.

Comment: ERROR:The term "Send-mail" is not recognized as the name of the cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: did you mean to use the cmdlet Send-MailMessage instead of Send-Mail?

Comment: Why are you using workflows in the first place? You don't seem to be using any of the features workflows provide.